# FastAPI cannot catch exception with status code 500

Tags: fastapi, exceptionhandler

I'm using Fastapi "0.104.1".
I'm able to catch every exception raised except for Internal Server Error 500.
Here is my code:
main.py

```
app = FastAPI(title='App')

app.add_exception_handler(400, exception_handler.exception_400_handler)
app.add_exception_handler(500, exception_handler.exception_500_handler)
```

exception_handler.py

```
async def exception_400_handler(request, exc):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
        content=jsonable_encoder({"error": {"message": exc.detail, "type": status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST}}),
    )

async def exception_500_handler(request, exc):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        content=jsonable_encoder({"error": {"message": exc.detail, "type": status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR}}),
    )
```

As said before, I'm able to catch exception with status 400, but not with status 500.
Example:

```
raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Item not found") # enter in the exception_400_handler
raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Error on update item") # NOT enter in the exception_500_handler
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: As I understand from source codes, FastAPI proceses `HTTPException(status_code=500,..)` differently from other error codes. It writes this handler to the `ServerErrorMiddleware` instead of adding into `ExceptionMiddleware`'s dict. And `ServerErrorMiddleware` will call your handler only if you don't use debug mode